# Criteria API count from grouped count

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I have a problem with Criteria API (JPA 2.0). I want to write code which returns the same result as query (select count from (select count from ... group by ...)):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a
    LEFT JOIN p ON a.id = p.a_id
    LEFT JOIN s ON a.id = s.a_id
    WHERE ... GROUP BY s.r_id
)
```

I wrote something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = slave.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> query = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);       
Root<A> entity = subquery.from(A.class);
Join<A, P> pJoin = entity.join("p", JoinType.LEFT);
Join<A, S> sJoin = entity.join("s", JoinType.LEFT);
subquery.select(builder.count(entity));
subquery.where(/*where predicate*/);
subquery.groupBy(sJoin.get("r"));
query.select(builder.count(subquery));
Long result = slave.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
```

But I get the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No criteria query roots were specified

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No. In my case subquery returns many rows. The count of the rows should be a result. Suppose you have an entity A (id: int, type: string). In the database you have rows like:
1 , 'a' |
2 , 'b' |
3 , 'a'
If you create query like:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a GROUP BY type;
you'll get two rows:
1 |
2
Now, if you create query like:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a GROUP BY type) AS x
you'll get count of the rows returned by subquery. And this is it what I want to achieve.